# Correct relationship between user table(present) and employee table(past and present)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I´m creating a Mysql database where the user table is implemented for login/access purposes and i need to create an employee table with current and past employees. The current employees should have a (1 to 1)corresponding user, past employees shouldn´t. What would be the best way of doing this? Is the design correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to have an `employee` table with an `employee_id` Primary Key.  This contains current and past employees.  I would then have a `user` table with an `employee_id` field which has a foreign key relationship with `employee.employee_id`.

When employees leave the record from `user` can be deleted to remove their access, while keeping their record in the `employee` table.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an attribute 'status' in employee table and assign 0 for past employees and 1 for present employees.
Take the employee_id as foreign key in Users table.
Make a join and check status at the login if the status is 1 then proceed to login.